# Como usar la opción nest con queries anidados con Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
const myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT id AS "tableAlias.id" FROM table AS tableAlias) AS records';

const records = sequelize.query(myQuery, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT, nest: true, raw: true, plain: true });

console.log(records); 

// { records: [{ "tableAlias.id": 1 }] }
```

Esto, o algo similar, funciona, pero la salida que quiero es así:

```
// { records: [{ tableAlias: { id: 1 } }] }
```

Como la típica estructura de objecto.

`nest: true` parece funcionar para queries simples, pero no para mi query anidadado.

Tengo queries anidados en mi query original porque necesito hacer `UNION ALL` y la API de Sequelize no lo soporta de manera nativa de la manera que quiero, entonces me tocó un `raw query`.

**Edición v1:**

También hago un `agg_json` del resultado porque devuelvo el resultado de múltiples queries y necesito que sea en una sola columna, lo cual me funciona.

Una idea de la estructura general del Query:

```
WITH (hago mi query anidado) AS resultadoQueryAnidado

SELECT (
(SELECT MIN(dates) FROM resultadoQueryAnidado) AS minDate, 
(SELECT json_agg(t.*) FROM resultadoQueryAnidado AS t) AS results, 
(SELECT COUNT(resultadoQueryAnidado) FROM resultadoQueryAnidado) AS count)
as myResults;
```

Hago esto de esta manera para poder paginar la consulta con la unión de los resultados de dos tablas no relacionadas.

**Edición v2:**

He estado depurando el query paso a paso y dejó de funcionar el nest cuando utilizo la función `json_agg` sobre el resultado del query.

```
return `SELECT json_agg(t.*) FROM (${queries}) as t`;
```

**Información adicional:**

- **sequelize:** `v6.30.0`
- **dottie:** `v2.0.2`

Comment: ¿Que versión de `sequelize` estas usando? ¿Tenes instaladado [`dottie.js`](https://github.com/mickhansen/dottie.js/)?

Comment: Sequelize v6 y dottie v2.0.2